# cronjob in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

I have tried almost everything that was there in the previous answers

Command: `/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/temp/index.php/ controller function`

This is the command I am using as my site is inside the temp folder of the particular domain
Earlier there were errors of `404` but now it shows

Could not open input file: `/home/username/public_html/temp/index.php/`

Any idea of the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot actually remember how CodeIgniter does its first step of routing - but I firmly believe it uses a rewrite rule to do it. As such, if you want to use codeIgniter's routing, you'll need to go through Apache/nginx. Sorry.

A good call would be `wget -q http://whatever.your.site.is/index.php/controller/function`, though.

Comment: the answer came out to be 
`/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/temp/index.php/ controller function`

Answer (score 1):

just remove the slash at the end so it shows like this

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/temp/index.php controller function
```